Calculating the Uncertainty in a Rolling-Averaged Time Series
I have a time series of data for the heat absorbed by the ocean (in Joules) since the 1957, downloaded from the NASA website:

The data consists of a series of measurements as well the standard error associated with each measurement.
In order to perform further calculations, I am smoothing the data using a centred rolling-average of $5$ years.
Rather than energy, I'll refer to the value of each data point in the series as simply $x$.
The rolling-average is found by calculating the mean of each point in the series $x_n$ in the standard way:
$$
\bar{x}_n = \frac{x_{n-2} + x_{n-1} + x_{n} + x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}}{5}
$$

whereby this result can be generalised into a centred rolling window of any size $m$ ( where $m$ is an odd number ):
$$
\bar{x}_n(m) =
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n-(m-1)/2}^{n+(m-1)/2} x_n}{m}
$$



My question is as follows:

How do I calculate the standard error in the smoothed datapoint, $\bar{x}_n$.
As far as I can tell, there is the standard error associated with each data point $x_n$, $\delta x_n$ ( given by that in the original dataset ), but there will be an additional uncertainty coming from the fact that it has been smoothed over a rolling window.
I would tentatively assume that this additional uncertainty can be calculated as:
$$
\delta x_{smoothing} = \frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{2}
$$

where $x_{max}$ and $x_{min}$ are the minimum and maximum values within the window.


To illustrate the problem further, here is a plot of the energy time series data with its associated uncertainty, together with the rolling average.

Ocean Heat Content Changes Since 1957:


In essence, I'm trying to plot what would be the Orange shaded region on the plot.
Once this has been determined I can then use this for further calculations.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this through !.

You are asking about the standard error of the mean.  Under the usual silly assumption that the errors of the points are independent, you add the squares of the errors (the variances of each point), divide by the number of points (here $5$) and take the square root.  If the errors on the points vary, you might want to weight your average by the inverse squares of the point errors because you want to count the most accurate one most.  The reason I said the assumption of independence is silly is that some of the error is systematic and averaging will not reduce the effect.  If there is a calibration error in the instruments, for example, it will not be reduced by averaging.

Many thanks for the quick response. So basically, I need to calculate the RMS error for each point. Looks like that's not covered in pandas rolling function - so a custom function may be needed for that. Thanks though!

I doubt these are measured with instruments, and are more likely to be modelled numbers based on other data.  Estimates of global average sea surface temperatures based on measurements and interpolation show much more volatility even with a rising trend.
